# Тень к png изображению

Tags: css

Можно ли средствами *CSS* установить тень для изображения в формате *PNG* так, чтобы тень была изогнутой и следовала за изгибами изображения?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться свойством [filter](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)

```css
#img {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 5px 5px #000);
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 5px 5px #000);
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://image.ibb.co/ebs4kL/share.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Подскажите, а можно так же сделать со свойством border?

Comment: @ИванСмирнов Можно попробовать добиться желаемого результата "поигравшись" всё с тем же `drop-shadow`. Убрать размытие (параметр перед цветом) и пробовать экспериментировать. Пример можно посмотреть [тут](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/bpr4ob6g/)

Comment: Я щас с мобилки и тени нету , т.е что ваш пример не кроссбраузерный

Comment: @LenovoID по ссылке, которую я также привёл в сообщении можно ознакомится со всеми нюансами совместимости.