# Как сделать у прозрачной картинки плавную подсветку?

Tags: css, css3

Есть картинка `png`, у которой хочу добиться плавной подстветки, но получается только жесткая с обрезанными краями - почему и можно ли исправить?

**Код:**

```css
.gray {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 75px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

img {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 75px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="gray">
  <div class="wrapper"><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b13/1810/ad/5bec961dfa11.png" width="233px" height="70px" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем понятно такой желаемые результат конечный должен быть...

Comment: наверно text-shadow

Comment: @Никита Фаст не понятно, что вы имеет ввиду, поясните.

Comment: @Air чтобы была подсветка тени, без выделения контурной рамки

Comment: напишите ЛОТОС буквами , подберите шрифт и ему уже задайте text-shadow и будет то что Вам нужно

Comment: @НикитаФаст, ему не тень текста нужна, а что-бы была внутреняя тень у `img` и при это не чувствовалась разница между тенью внутренней у `img` и внешней его контейнера.... Если я правильно понял

Comment: @Air на css это не сделать

Comment: можно добавить пару дополнительный блоков для обертки и постепенно подгонять цвет...

Comment: @Вася [ТАК](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oadmvr?editors=1100) ?

Comment: @Air  такой нужен результат ? [codepen](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oadmvr?editors=1100)

Comment: @Никита Фаст хитро, но в целом неплохо!

Comment: @Вася ответом написать ?

Comment: @Никита Фаст записывайте, я подтвержу, но если еще будет способ интересный, то пусть продолжится тема

Comment: тут только интересней тема на svg может быть - но я в нём не силён

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Тень к png изображению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477847/%d0%a2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%ba-png-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишем буквы стилизуем поворачиваем увеличиваем и text-shadow - и результат

```css
.gray {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: roboto;
  transform: translateY(-120px);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

p span {
  display: inline-block;
}

p span:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(-30deg)translate(0, -15px);
}

p span:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translateY(-35px)translateX(-18px)rotate(-22deg);
}

p span:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translateY(-40px)translateX(-29px)rotate(0);
}

p span:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: translateY(-30px)translateX(-38px)rotate(20deg);
}

p span:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: rotate(30deg)translate(-55px, 10px);
}

p span {
  text-shadow: -3px -1px 40px yellow;
  color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="gray">
  <div class="wrapper"><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b13/1810/ad/5bec961dfa11.png" width="233px" height="70px" />
    <p>
      <span>Л</span>
      <span>О</span>
      <span>Т</span>
      <span>О</span>
      <span>С</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну значит я не правильно понял  вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще такой вариант, но вот в `IE` не будет работать

```css
.gray {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
}

img {
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px -15px 15px yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="gray">
  <div class="wrapper"><img src="https://b.radikal.ru/b13/1810/ad/5bec961dfa11.png" width="233px" height="70px" /></div>
</div>
```